# Alternative to GROUP BY, when a WINDOW isn't working properly.. SQL

Tags: sql, psql, google-bigquery

This I feel is a simple answer, but I just can't seem to get it right..

Initially I ran two queries, because I couldn't figure out how to fix this problem in one.. This was the query for my initial table "free2":

```
WITH prep AS (
        SELECT *,
            (((odds - 1)/div) + 1) AS ew_odds,
            (odds*size) AS possible_win_returns,
            (((odds - 1)/div) + 1)*size AS possible_ew_returns
        FROM scratch.free
    ),

    prof AS(
        SELECT *,
            (possible_ew_returns+possible_win_returns) AS possible_total_win,
            (possible_win_returns*win) - size AS win_profit,
            (possible_ew_returns*places) - size AS ew_profit
        FROM prep 
    )

    SELECT 
        date_trunc(prof.date, DAY) AS DAY,
        SUM(ew_odds) AS ew_odds,
        SUM(size) AS size,
        SUM(odds) AS odds,
        SUM(places) AS places,
        SUM(div) AS divisor,
        SUM (total_size) AS total_size,
        SUM(won) AS profit,
        SUM(ew_profit) AS ew_prof,
        SUM(win_profit) AS win_prof,
        SUM(possible_total_win) AS pos_tot_win,
        SUM(possible_ew_returns) AS pos_ew_ret,
        SUM(possible_win_returns) AS pos_win_ret
    FROM prof
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY day DESC
```

which grouped all my sums by day, which is what I'm trying to do. Then I LEFT JOINED the second table onto the first by running this second query:

```
SELECT d.*,
    f.ew_odds,
    f.size,
    f.odds,
    f.places,
    f.divisor,
    f.total_size,
    f.profit,
    f.ew_prof AS ew_profit,
    f.win_prof AS win_profit,
    f.pos_tot_win AS possible_total_win,
    f.pos_ew_ret AS possible_ew_returns,
    f.pos_win_ret AS possible_win_returns,
    date_trunc(d.day, week) AS week,
    date_trunc(d.day, month) AS month,
    date_trunc(d.day, year) AS year,
    date_trunc(d.day, quarter) AS quarter
FROM scratch.free2 AS f
LEFT JOIN accounts.daily_movement AS d 
    ON d.day = f.day
```

Which as I said, worked fine. However, I need to replicate this as a whole in one query. I can't do this directly, since a GROUP BY clause interferes with LEFT JOIN. So i tried to make all of the first table's values, a window function:

```
prof AS (
    SELECT *,
        (possible_ew_returns+possible_win_returns) AS possible_total_win,
        (possible_win_returns*win) - size AS win_profit,
        (possible_ew_returns*places) - size AS ew_profit,
        date_trunc(date, DAY) AS day
    FROM calculations 
)

sum AS (
    SELECT prof.day,
    SUM(prof.ew_odds) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS ew_odds,
    SUM(prof.size) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS size,
    SUM(prof.odds) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS odds,
    SUM(prof.places) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        AS places,
    SUM(prof.div) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS divisor,
    SUM(prof.total_size) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS total_size,
    SUM(prof.won) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS won,
    SUM(prof.rico) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS rico,
    SUM(prof.won) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS profit,
    SUM(prof.ew_profit)
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS ew_prof,
    SUM(prof.win_profit) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS win_prof,
    SUM(prof.possible_total_win) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS possible_tot_win,
    SUM(prof.possible_ew_returns) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS possible_ew_returns,
    SUM(prof.possible_win_returns) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY prof.day RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
        AS possible_win_returns
    FROM prof)

SELECT 
    sum.*
    d.total_euros,
    d.profit_bf_exp,
    d.percentage_profit,
    d.profit_aft_exp,
    d.brendan_profit,
    d.brendan_transactions,
    d.brendan_daily,
    d.brendan_percentage,
    d.michael_profit,
    d.michael_transactions,
    d.michael_daily,
    d.michael_percentage,
    d.general_expenses,
    d.thiago_payment,
    d.pedro_payment,
    d.rodrigues_payment,
    d.felipe_payment,
    d.expenses_notes,
    d.details
FROM sum
LEFT JOIN accounts.daily_movement AS d ON d.day = sum.day
ORDER BY sum.day DESC
```

I tried changing the RANGE of each WINDOW to ROWS.. but it's still wrong.

What is happening is that all of the grouping per day is not happening correctly, it is showing the date to be singular, and the sum of each value as the same, but there will be about 10-20 rows of the exact same SUMS and DAYs data..

This is what the "size" column and first 5 rows of "day DESC" should look like:

> Row   day     size
>   1   2017-04-30  1679.27
>   2   2017-04-29  7292.809999999996
>   3   2017-04-28  3247.04
>   4   2017-04-27  2209.2000000000003
>   5   2017-04-26  2932.42

but instead, it comes out like this:

> Row   day size
>   1   2017-04-30  1679.27
>   2   2017-04-30  1679.27
>   3   2017-04-30  1679.27
>   4   2017-04-30  1679.27
>   5   2017-04-30  1679.27

How do I prevent the repetition of SUMs and days in the data?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from putting the first query into a view then referencing it in your 2nd query?

Comment: "I need to replicate this as a whole in one query. I can't do this directly, since a GROUP BY clause interferes with LEFT JOIN. "  I have no idea what that refers to.  You should really simplify the queries so it is easier for others to follow.  Then, the first set of queries starts with `scratch.free`.  The second starts with `calculations`.  I really can't follow what you are attempting at all.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, these are snippets of a larger query, which I've tried to condense as is. If you check the answers, it has been solved in a manner in which I thought I'd tried already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which as I said, worked fine. However, I need to replicate this as a whole in one query...

Try below (for BigQuery StandardSQL)

This is just simple assembly of your two steps in one as you wanted!
If, as you claim, they work for you separatelly - below must work for you too!

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH prep AS (
  SELECT *,
    (((odds - 1)/DIV) + 1) AS ew_odds,
    (odds*size) AS possible_win_returns,
    (((odds - 1)/DIV) + 1)*size AS possible_ew_returns
  FROM scratch.free
),
prof AS(
  SELECT *,
    (possible_ew_returns+possible_win_returns) AS possible_total_win,
    (possible_win_returns*win) - size AS win_profit,
    (possible_ew_returns*places) - size AS ew_profit
  FROM prep 
),
free2 AS (
  SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC(prof.date, DAY) AS DAY,
    SUM(ew_odds) AS ew_odds,
    SUM(size) AS size,
    SUM(odds) AS odds,
    SUM(places) AS places,
    SUM(DIV) AS divisor,
    SUM (total_size) AS total_size,
    SUM(won) AS profit,
    SUM(ew_profit) AS ew_prof,
    SUM(win_profit) AS win_prof,
    SUM(possible_total_win) AS pos_tot_win,
    SUM(possible_ew_returns) AS pos_ew_ret,
    SUM(possible_win_returns) AS pos_win_ret
  FROM prof
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT d.*,
  f.ew_odds,
  f.size,
  f.odds,
  f.places,
  f.divisor,
  f.total_size,
  f.profit,
  f.ew_prof AS ew_profit,
  f.win_prof AS win_profit,
  f.pos_tot_win AS possible_total_win,
  f.pos_ew_ret AS possible_ew_returns,
  f.pos_win_ret AS possible_win_returns,
  DATE_TRUNC(d.day, week) AS week,
  DATE_TRUNC(d.day, month) AS month,
  DATE_TRUNC(d.day, year) AS year,
  DATE_TRUNC(d.day, quarter) AS quarter
FROM free2 AS f
LEFT JOIN accounts.daily_movement AS d 
ON d.day = f.day
```

Comment: Hey Mikhail, thanks for your answer, I don't know why it didn't work the first time when I tried it, but it did now!